# how to call already defined clickhandler using getElementbyid... (React)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

problem: i want to call some element's clickHandler which inside of 'onclick' attribute.

in the situation like this:

```
 function Foo(word) {console.log('foo says ${word}');}
 const clickHandler = ()=>{Foo("hello");}
 <div id="myElement" onclick={clickHandler}>
  ...some children...
 </div>
```

I want to call `myElement`'s `clickHandler` with `getElementById()` method. I tried below but did not work.

```
const myElement = document.getElementById("myElement");
myElement.onclick(); // <- did not work! i want to call clickHandler like this!
```

is there any method to call some element's handler fucntion outside of it's scope? bytheway i'm using React.js.

Comment: XY problem probably

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you'll need `useRef` hook and the `ref` attribute on the element in question.   Instead of using `document.getElementById` at all. This is the commonest method.

Otherwise you can create a synthetic click Event and send it to the element.